# Python - Dynamic Line Chart Marker Colours based on an another column

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, linechart, markers

I'm trying to create a simple line chart in **Python**, for each customer I want to show a single line showing the trend based on the value (y-axis) and date (x-axis). The marker colours should be based on the colour field.

Please find below for the sample data and the expected output (sorry for my scribbling)

[Sample Data Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCUps.png)

[Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/586Ce.png)

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is to first use the `plot` function to plot the lines, for example in black, and then use `scatter` to plot the colored markers. Here I show an example:

I generate data similar to yours as follows (I suppose you are storing the data in a pandas dataframe):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

columns = ['CustID', 'Date', 'Value', 'Color']
data = []

np.random.seed(42)
for cus_id in np.arange(1, 5):
    for date in ['jan', 'feb', 'mar', 'apr']:
        data.append([cus_id, date, np.random.randint(20,35),
                     np.random.choice(['red', 'blue', 'green'])])

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=columns)
```

At this point, `df` contains [this table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4JSL8.png).

Finally, to plot your line chart:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
for _, df_cus in df.groupby('CustID'):
    ax.plot(df_cus.Date, df_cus.Value, color='black', zorder=0)
    ax.scatter(df_cus.Date, df_cus.Value, color=df_cus.Color, zorder=1)
```

[Here's the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ztGW.png)

I use `zorder` to make sure the scatter plots are always on top of the black lines.